# simplifying debugging of next.js (client and server) in VS code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, next.js

My current method is to run `npm run dev` in a terminal. which uses `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev` (i tried it without `cross-env` and it wont run).

then i attach a node debugger to the running process with the following script in VS code

```
      {
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 9229,
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "pwa-node",
      }
```

and then finally i launch chrome with another debugger script

```
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

I have tried the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55967569/1807486) and the process don't run.

I have also tried this configuration (both `node` and `node-pwa` variants) they run but dont seem to actually do any debugging, nor are there any messages in the console (or debug console).

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM: node",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "run-script",
          "dev"
        ],
        "port": 9229,
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ]
      }
```

idealy, i would like to be able to press a single button and have it all launch up for me, currently it is a 3 step process, but i would happily take converting the `attach` task to a launch task.